# Accessing static file for window.open no longer works in appengine 1.6.3

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404, window.open

This was working until I downloaded the new version.  Now I get a 404 error.

app.yamp is:

```
application: gamekicks
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: PIL
  version: latest
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: webob
  version: latest  
- name: jinja2
  version: latest  

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: static/stylesheets
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images
- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js
- url: /templates
  static_dir: /templates  
- url: /.*
  script: gamekicks.app
```

The javascript code that no longer works:

```
<input type="button" value="Chat" 
       onClick="window.open('chatmain.html','chatwindow','width=400,height=200')">
```

I had to move my templates dir out from under static/ as a work around for jinja2's path not working correctly once I deployed the app.  It worked fine locally.  Any ideas on why this was not working as well?  All the other static files are accessed correctly.

Comment: Where is chatmain.html stored, and what's the absolute URL the browser will try to fetch it at?  In general, templates should never be static at all, and actual static HTML pages should be in a different directory from your templates and served by their own handler.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem.  I restored the directory structure back to the /static/templates for local testing - problem solved locally.  Then I deployed again, and got the error loading the template. Thinking this through, I realized I was setting the jinja path to "static/template" - when it should be simply "template", since the app.yaml was accesssing the html files as template.  So, a noob error.  I just changed the jinja path and now everything works fine.  Hope this helps some other person getting started with python and jinja.